# Handling Empty or invalid date in deserialisation Json.net

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a JSON object with a similar structure below

```
{
details:[

    {
       name:"sandeep",dob:"15/04/1984"
    },
    {
       name:"alex",dob:""
    },
    {
       name:"paul",dob:"25/02/1990"
    }]

}
```

This is the class to which I am trying to deserialize

```
class users
{
   public string name{get;set;}
   public datetime dob{get;set;}
}
```

This is how I am deserializing

```
   var dateTimeConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = format };
   List<users> usr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<user>>(responseBody, dateTimeConverter);
```

But when deserializing, its triggering

```
String '' was not recognised as a valid date time
```

So Could you please help how handle empty or invalid dates in deserializing

Comment: Replace [`IsoDateTimeConverter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/IsoDateTimeConverter.cs) with your own `JsonConverter<DateTime>` that calls [`DateTime.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_TryParse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_System_DateTime__) and returns some default value in the event of an error.

Comment: Be sure to use [`JsonSerializer.Culture`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Culture.htm) to parse in the correct locale.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that the json may have an empty date value, so you must handle empty dates like:

```
var deserializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions();
deserializeOptions.Converters.Add(new MyDateTimeJsonConverter());

myobject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<users>(jsonString, 
           deserializeOptions);


class MyDateTimeJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
  public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer 
  serializer)
  {
    // implement in case you're serializing it back
  }

  public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object 
    existingValue,
    JsonSerializer serializer)
  {
     var dataString = (string) reader.Value;
     // one way to handle empty/invalid dates
     return DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out var dateValue) ? dateValue : DateTime.MinValue;
  }

  public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
  {
    return objectType == typeof(DateTime);
  }
}
```

or make **dob** property a nullable like:

```
class users
{
   public string name {get; set;}
   public DateTime? dob {get; set;}
}
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks a lot. Made it nullable which solved the problem pretty straight.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything right. just change DateTime to nullable

```
class users
{
   public string name{get;set;}
   public Datetime? dob{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Making it Nullable fixed it straight. Thanks